# Spotify api recently_played returns empty list

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to get user's recently played tracks from spotify api. Here is the code I use for it:

```
def get_recently_played(uid):
    token = get_token(uid)
    print(token.token)
    # headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.token}
    # resp = requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played", headers=headers).content
    resp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token.token).current_user_recently_played()
    return resp
```

I've tried two options: with spotipy and with requests (commented lines). However, the response in both cases is:

```
{'items': [], 'next': None, 'cursors': None, 'limit': 50, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played?limit=50'}
```

The only thing that changes is limit (with requests limit = 20, with spotipy limit = 50). Why does it happen? I don't even have a "total" field, which should be there according to the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-recently-played).

The get_token function checks if token is expired and if so refreshes the token before returning it.

Comment: Ok, turns out it was a problem with just one account, when I used literally the same code for another one it worked. Still, if anyone has faced a similar problem I would be glad to hear the probable reason.